# In Enterprise canon in the same timeline of Beyond?

Tags: star-trek, canon, continuity, star-trek-beyond

We know that the accident that causes the universes of Star Trek to diverge happend in the XXIII century. We also know that everything that happens after it (and so TOS, TNG, DS9 and VOY) is set in the new timeline. But what about Star Trek Enterprise, which is set in the XXII century? Is it also set within the new movie timeline? Is it canon within it?

Comment: May they be just related questions?. What I asked is if Enterprise happened in the new timeline and if it has to be considered canon within it.

Comment: There's no definitive statement on-screen, but given that the timeline was altered starting with the destruction of the USS Kelvin, long after Archer's Enterprise's adventures, it does not make any logical sense that the alteration of the timeline would travel to the past as well.  That being said, just because it's not logical, doesn't mean Star Trek won't eventually do it.  It's just a technobabble hand-wave away.

Comment: It seems evident this alternate universe was already considerably different given the distinct technological and aesthetic differences already in place when the Narada crosses over.

Comment: everything pre-kelvin should be the same. Enterprise happened close to 100 years before the nurada destroys the kelvin, so any temporal ripples should not effect the Enterprise Series at all.

Answer (score 1):

This is complicated...

We have Timeline A which is the timeline that is considered "Prime" canon universally (even though it's actually several timeline and didn't happen that way in reality canon)

Timeline A exists the beginning of the Universe that we see all the way up to the 31st? century. Then Daniels (or other people from his time) travels back to the era of Enterprise and they start going down Timeline B.

Timeline B overwrites Timeline A, but then the knot that was created is fixed and resest the Timeline of B to Timeline A...

So between the beginning of Enterprise and this reset point, all that happens is in Timeline B, but we know that some variation of most of those events happened in timeline A. After the reset we are back on Timeline A's path where in everything "should" happen as it was told to us in all the formerly canon series.

JJ Abram's Star Trek's first part happens 50 years after all "Prime" Timeline A's stories and sends them back to at least 20 years before TOS start and at least 80 years ENT and this is where the timeline diverges into Timeline C or "The Kelvin Timeline".

So... Part of Enterprise takes place in the same timeline as The Kelvin Timeline, but most do not in terms events that actually happened in that universe, but some variation of most of them did. Just like in the Prime Timeline.

To answer your question more succinctly...
Yes, No, and sorta...

Comment: Your answer is a bit confusing to me. According to Memory Alpha, Enterprise NX-01 was launched in 2151 (https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Enterprise_(NX-01) ). The timeline-splitting event that created your "Timeline C" occurred in 2233 (https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/USS_Kelvin). The events of Enterprise take much less than 82 years to complete, so Enterprise takes place in the pre-split timeline that is common to both the Prime and Kelvin timelines.  Sure, the future time travel that occurs in Enterprise complicates things somewhat, but not enough to be material to the question.